# Django celery worker error on ec2 trying to start daemon process with systemd

Tags: django, linux, celery, ubuntu-18.04, django-celery

I am trying to use celery as a daemon on my ec2 server and have so far been following [this](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#usage-systemd) tutorial. Every time I try to start a celery worker daemon the log returns with these errors:

```
systemd[1]: celery.service: Failed to load environment files: No such file or directory
systemd[1]: celery.service: Failed to run 'start' task: No such file or directory
systemd[1]: celery.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start Celery Service.
```

When I run the worker using

```
celery -A project_name worker --loglevel=INFO
```

celery runs as expected but shuts down when i log out of my server. Any help figuring out this error would be much appreciated as I am a complete beginner here. All relevant files are provided below:

celery.conf

```
# celery.conf

CELERYD_NODES="w1"
CELERY_BIN="path/to/project/directory/env/bin/celery"
CELERY_APP="project_name"
CELERYD_MULTI="multi"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
```

celery.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=username
Group=groupname
EnvironmentFile=/path/to/environmentfile/celery.conf
WorkingDirectory=path/to/project/directory/env/bin/
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} -A ${CELERY_APP} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}'
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} -A ${CELERY_APP} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

django settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'profiles_api',
    "push_notifications",

]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ]
}


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'profiles_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'profiles_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'name',
        'USER': 'name',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'HOST': '', # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '',
    },
}
#

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'profiles_api.UserProfile'

STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'

# celery
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:5555'
RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:5555'
ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed the problem by editing my celery.service file to look as such

## celery.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

    [Service]
    #Type=forking
    User=username
    Group=groupname
    KillMode=control-group
    RemainAfterExit=yes
    WorkingDirectory=path/to/project/directory
    Restart=yes
    #PassEnvironment=CELERYD_NODES CELERY_BIN CELERY_APP CELERYD_MULTI CELERYD_PID_FILE CELERYD_LOG_FILE CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL
    
    ExecStart=path/to/project/directory/env/bin/celery -A project_name worker --loglevel=INFO
    
    ExecStop=path/to/project/directory/env/bin/celery -A project_name worker --loglevel=INFO
    
    
    
    ExecReload=path/to/project/directory/env/bin/celery -A project_name worker --loglevel=INFO
    
    
    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```